# Associated functionality with a button in HTML - Not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code for a button and a function to give alert when clicked on that button. Its giving the alert when I load the page but not when I click on the button. What is wrong with this code?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
b1 = document.getElementById("b0");
b1.onclick = message();

function message() {
 alert("You clicked a button");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Checking button functionality!</h1>
<button id="b0">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is likely throwing an undefined error on `b1` because the DOM isn't loaded at the time you search for the element with id `b0`.

You need to either update your script to query the DOM in the `load` event, or move it *after* the element you are getting. It is common practice to place scripts before the closing `</body>` tag.

E.g.

```
<head>
<script>
  function message() {
    alert("You clicked a button");
  };

  window.onload = function() {
    b1 = document.getElementById('b0');
    b1.onclick = message;
  };
</script>
</head>
...
```

Note also that I omitted the parentheses in the `onclick` assignment. You want to assign the function to the event, not call the function then assign it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the script below the button (best before `</body>`) and to change

```
b1.onclick = message();
```

to

```
b1.onclick = message;
```

otherwise you don't assign the function but it's return value.

Or even better: (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))

```
b1.addEventListener('click', message);
```

Comment: Thank you! You mentioned a good reference in your answer but Quantastical's answer is more precise. Voted for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are already executing the function and assigning its return value to the onclick event instead of the function reference itself. Remove the brackets:
        `b1.onclick = message;`

Also, you have to move the script block below the markup, or the button will not yet exist when you try to add the click handler to it.

Comment: Thank you Connum! As Quantastical's answer is more explanatory than this, I am marking it as the answer but I am voting for your answer too.